# Middle ground between [0] and loop through all on getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have a code which initially would only activate the first occurrence of ElementsByClassName("thishere"), even if later occurrences in the document were clicked.

```js
function zxcv(el) {
el.style.display = "none";
el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere")[0].style.display = 'block';
return false;
}
```

Changes made (see below) means it can loop through the all the elements ByClassName("thishere") when any ElementsByClassName("thishere") is clicked but I'm actually looking for something in-between; I'd like only the specific occurrence of the element which is clicked to be activated, not all occurrences at the same time.

My expertise is very limited so I hope I've used the correct terminology and provided the relevant information. Help would be much appreciated.

```js
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    var elements = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
    for(var i in elements) {
           elements[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Below is the HTML used:

```html
<div><a href="stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" rel="follow" onClick="zxcv(this)">Stackoverflow</a><div class="thishere" style="display:none;">On Your Way To Expert Help</div>
```

Comment: how are you calling zxcl? You say clicked, what do you mean? Is this function called in an event? can you supply us with some html?

Comment: I have added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
function zxcv(el){
    var elements=el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
    for(var i=0,len=elements.length;i<len;i++){
        !function(i){
           elements[i].style.display='block';
        }(i)
    }
    el.style.display="none";
    return false
}
```

`for... in` just works for JavaScript objects, by what I know.

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be behaving the same way the code in the original post.

Comment: Wrapping the style change in a self-invoked function accomplishes what?

Comment: I didn't get well the question, but this is a small fix for the loop, at least. Sorry if I delay to reply the comments, my network isn't good at these days.

Comment: Please see it working here (remembering that my network delayed many hours and times to allow me load JSFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/1qjch3ky/

Comment: @Pro Hands - I'm not sure what to do with this. See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915045/middle-ground-between-0-and-loop-through-all-on-getelementsbyclassname#comment55636985_33915536

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

HTML:

```
<div class="thishere">
<h1 style="display:none;">CleverPeople</h1>
<a href="stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" rel="follow">www.Stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>

<div class="thishere">
<h1  style="display:none;">MoreCleverPeople</h1>
<a href="stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" rel="follow">www.Stackoverflowmore.com</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
     $('.thishere').on('click',function(e){
     $(this).find('a').hide();
     $(this).find('h1').show();
     //return false;
    })
  });
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with this or how to make relevant to my situation. I've included HTML in my original post; would you please be able to assist & show me specifically to my case?

Comment: Why are you using quoting format (`>`) when you're not quoting?

Comment: @f484126,if you want only first occurrence value use $('.thishere:first'), why are you going with for loop, and please give a proper fiddle link with the complete code.

Comment: @f484126 There's an error in your code because you're calling `zxcv`, but it's a function that is inside the document onload function, so you can't use it (by what I seen in JSFiddle). Please change the `OnLoad` option  from JSFiddle, at the top, in `Frameworks and Extensions` to `No wrap - in <body>`.

Comment: @Jhon Carpenter thanks we're nearly there! I would like only the DIV of the link clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/f484126/xq4ssjd3/6/

Comment: @Jhon Carpenter this way doesn't seem to load the URL on click, just shows the text....

Comment: @f484126, i prevent that action by adding return false, please remove that, then URL will also work.
https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/xq4ssjd3/9/

Comment: @Jhon Carpenter Thank you but I still am having trouble with this. The link does not seem to open in a new window, but appends on to the end of the current URL.